# Java2D drawString very slow?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

I'm trying to do display some very basic information into a window using Java Swing/AWT 2D Graphics. At this point, I'm just drawing some strings, but although this task does not seem that hard, it runs incredible slow.

At drawing nothing, I can repaint at around 100 FPS. With 1 string, around 30 FPS. With 20 strings, around 3 FPS.

Minimal example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();
        JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
                g2.drawString(Integer.toString(counter++), 20, 20);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 50);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 60);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 70);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 80);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 90);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 100);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 110);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 120);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 130);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 140);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 150);
                g2.drawString("HALLO", 50, 160);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 160);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 170);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 180);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 190);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 100);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 110);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 120);
                g2.drawString("DIES IST NUR EINT EST FÜR EINEN LANGENSTRING", 200, 130);
                g2.dispose();
            }
        };
        frame.add(pane);

        while (true) {
            pane.repaint();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(480, 272);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }
}
```

I'm running on a raspberry pi 3b+, which is not a really fast machine but should be able to display some strings. Timing the functions using `System.nanoTime` shows that both the main loop and the `paintComponent` function are below 1ms which adds even more to my confusion.

Am I fundamentally missing something?

Comment: "this task does not seem that hard" - well, rendering text is harder than you'd think, there's quite a lot of calculation needed to get which pixels should be colored and which shouldn't. Besides that I can imagine that hardware acceleration is not enabled or even available - if that's true then everything would have to be done in software which is really slow.

Comment: Since you are trying to show "very basic information", why don't you simply use components? Like `JLabel` or so..

Comment: Btw, you did write you were "timing" the methods. Does that mean you did write the times and fps to the command line? If yes then that's most likely the culprit for the slow "rendering".

Comment: Another possible problem in your code would be `g2.dispose();`. From the JavaDoc on `dispose()`: "...For efficiency, programmers shouldcall dispose when finished usinga Graphics object only if it was createddirectly from a component or another Graphics object." - you didn't create `g2` so you shouldn't dispose it yourself.

Comment: Hmmm well - the raspberry is capable of rendering the whole raspian interface including desktop items with text, file explorer etc - without having any FPS issues. This doesn't seem to fit.

Will try to use a JLabel!

Timing methods are commented out, same problem! Anyhow, I can see the FPS approximatly at the string that represents counter - it goes up really slowly.

Commenting dispose() also doesn't change anything.

Comment: You should NOT dispose the `Graphics` because the JPanel is going to continue using it.

Comment: Okay, using JLabels actually is really alot faster. (Altough that's not really too easy to understand for me - in the end, the JLabel has to render the string too?)

Comment: *"using JLabels actually is really a lot faster"* Tip: Add @GeorgeZ. (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: George and @Thomas made good points, but I'm getting north of 2000 FPS from that code as is. Here is output I tweaked the source to show `java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_45-b15
java.awt.graphicsenv: sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
os.name: Windows 8.1
FPS: 2531
FPS: 2696
FPS: 2739
FPS: 2617
FPS: 2531
FPS: 2350`

Comment: Well, comparing rendering the strings each frame vs. using JLabels wouldn't be really comparable. Unless you've tweaked the rendering of the labels they're probably only rendered once (at least into some internal buffer).

Comment: This `while (true) {
            pane.repaint();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }` loop makes no sense. And it’s burning one CPU core and forcing unnecessary synchronization between the main thread and the event dispatch thread. As you noted yourself, it’s not the actual painting that is slow.

Answer (score 1):

How about draw your strings into a BufferedImage first:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(pane.getSize().width, pane.getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2D = bi.createGraphics();
g2D.drawString("HALLO", 50, 50);
...
g2D.dispose();
```

cache it, and in your paintComponent(), just draw the image

```
g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
```